# How to print SSSP in order in C?

Tags: c

I have a working code that prints the SSSP from destination to source, but I want it to be in reverse i.e. source to destination.

Let's say that this generates a path of **10 9 0** and another that is **5 7 0**, where 3 is the destination and 1 is the source/starting node.

I want it to print **0 9 10** and **0 5 7** instead.

Comment: Fairly straight forward - https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/dijkstra.html#implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Use a recursive path printer.  You have:

```
for (i = 1; i <= T->vertices; i++)
{
    if (T->parent[i] != -1)
    {
        printf("SSSP Distance from %d->%d is %d: {%d",
               T->visited[i], i, T->distance[i], i);

        j = i;
        while(T->parent[j] != -1)
        {   //the path is printed backwards, but still in order.
            j = T->parent[j];
            printf("<-%d", j);
        }
        printf("}\n");
    }   
}
```

Consider adding a function:

```
static void path_printer(SomeType *T, size_t i)
{
    size_t j = T->parent[i];
    if (j != -1)
    {
        path_printer(T, j);
        if (T->parent[j] != -1)
            printf("->");
        printf("%d", i);
     }
}
```

and revise your loop to:

```
for (i = 1; i <= T->vertices; i++)
{
    if (T->parent[i] != -1)
    {
        printf("SSSP Distance from %d->%d is %d: {",
               T->visited[i], i, T->distance[i]);
        path_printer(T, i);
        printf("}\n");
    }   
}
```

The recursive function prints the list items in reverse order; the rest is cosmetic.